High thread count even with low request count in azure web app
I'm facing an issue with high thread count in my webapp, when I compare the number of requests to the server vs the thread count, it doesn't look proportional or make sense, I understand thread blocking code cause high thread count and I eliminated such code from my .Net API but the threads are still high, even at sleeping hours, which makes me think there's something else that could be the reason, how can I investigate this better?


Hi @mahmoudmh, can you please share the code
